# img in grid taking up more space on Firefox than Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In the example below, Firefox (as well as Safari) use the img's origin size rather than make it fit into the grid like Chrome does. Is there a work around for these browsers?

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
  $("#first").append(`
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x650" />
    </div>
    `);  
}
```

```css
.flex {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
.footer {
  height: 20%;
}
.upper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="flex">
  <div class='upper'>
    <div id="grid">
      <div id='first' class="inner-grid">
      </div>
      <div>
      test
      </div>
      <div class="inner-grid">
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `.item`. https://jsfiddle.net/f38o1ofu/1/